# Cyclcic imports fix. Dependency cycle detected

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

Consider this short snippets in each of its files.

```
// a.ts
import { getModuleB } from "./auxiliaryModule";

export const a = 2;

const b = getModuleB();
console.log(b);

// b.ts
import { getModuleA } from "./auxiliaryModule";

export const b = 1;

const a = getModuleA();
console.log(a);

// auxiliaryModule.ts
import { a } from "./a";
import { b } from "./b";

export const getModuleA = () => {
  return a;
};

export const getModuleB = () => {
  return b;
};
```

I created the auxiliaryModule to get rid of the `Dependency cycle detected` error by trying to "Move the shared code into a third module" as suggested in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). However the error does not go away.

What is the solution to remove this error and the pattern to use code from two modules interchangeably and safely?

Comment: This structure doesn't make sense. Why do you need such a dependency cycle? a needs and imports b. b needs and imports a. That's a logical infinite loop. You have to go one step back and think about the problem you're trying to solve. Assuming it were possible to run this code, it would produce an infinite output. Can you describe the expected behavior and output?

Comment: I just want to use functions between two modules interchangeably. I just want to use a function from a.ts in b.ts and a function from b.ts in a.ts.

Comment: You want an infinite loop of outputs: `1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...`? What is the expected output and how would you use this code?

Comment: nope. I used a constant example for simplicity. Just want to use something (a constant, function or whatever) from `a` to `b` and from `b` to `a` in both directions. Meaning I want to use something defined on `a` imported and used in `b` and viceversa.

Comment: My question is, why do you need it? It doesn't make sense. You want two modules. The initialization of module `a` requires to completely evaluate module `b` and the initialization of module `b` requires to completely evaluate module `a`. You shouldn't try to fix this code. You should find out why you have this requirement and fix that. Usually you would use lazy or deferred imports, but that's not possible in your case.

Comment: i once had this error. i guess it's an indicator of a bad design. however, i got around this (or made it worse) by *slightly* re-designing to include a method to inject one module into another. `a` will only call its internal `_b` which will be set from outside using a method `a.init(b)`.